# How to add hyperlink on reference produced by achemso package?

Tags: achemso

I am using the `achemso` package to handle citations and produce a reference list. I have the following working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{PeopleWhoKnow.bib}
@article{Kojima2009,
author = {
Kojima, A and
Teshima, K and
Shirai, Y and
Miyasaka, T
},
doi = {10.1021/ja809598r},
journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
title = {Organometal Halide Perovskites as Visible-Light Sensitizers for Photovoltaic Cells},
url = {http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja809598r},
year = {2009},
volume = {131},
number = {17},
pages = {6050--6051},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{usetitle = true, doi = true}
\usepackage{hyperref, doi}
\renewcommand*{\doitext}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
Some text plus \cite{Kojima2009}.
\bibliographystyle{achemso} %This seems to do nothing
\bibliography{PeopleWhoKnow}
\end{document}
```

However, I would rather not include the DOI at all and instead have the hyperlink be on the entire reference (although I would be okay with the hyperlink on the title). Is this possible with the `achemso` package?